# Which movie zombie apocalypse has the most screen time?

Tags: movie, zombie-apocalypse

As of 2016, which big screen zombie apocalypse movie has the most screentime (in terms of minutes) in the movies? Please include sequels and spinoffs as long as it's **the same apocalypse.**

Comment: What do you mean by "screen time"? Are we talking longest time in theatres, longest time between first showing and last showing, highest box office gross or most screens aired on?

Comment: Or just "longest movie"?

Comment: I'm guessing walking dead by now should be the clear lead of "screen time", with 2 series with various seasons.

Comment: @Valorum Really? You listed everything except what I asked.  I was fairly sure this one was pretty straight forward. Which big screen zombie apocalypse has the most on screen minutes(screen time). It could be the longest big screen movie, it could be the zombie apocalypse with the most sequels that add up to the most minutes, but not a TV show.  I'll let you guys edit, reopen, scratch your heads, or whatever. Because: Whatever.

Comment: @valorum - I've edited to make the question clearer. I suspect the answer is either Resident Evil or the Romero "... of the dead" films

Comment: Resident Evil films add up to 8 hours 1 minute.  Funnily enough, they're all basically the same length (between 1:34 and 1:40 long).  The Romero films (I counted 7 in the " of the dead" films) add up to 10:36.

Comment: Although technically speaking, I'm not sure that all the Romero films are "Apocalyptic" in nature, since at least some of them occurred before law&order broke down.  I'm unsure, so I lumped my comment above simply as "zombie" films.

Comment: [Army of Darkness](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106308/) takes Ash back to 1300AD.  I don't know whether that qualifies as a 600 year long Apocalypse or not.  Possibly, this is a different question altogether, but seemed a fun notion.

Comment: @Valorum You pinged yourself?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - My granny used to say that if you do that too often, you'll go blind.

Answer (score 7):

#### TL;DR:  The series that began with *Night of the Living Dead* is probably the longest.

---

## George A. Romero's installments:

***Night of the Living Dead*** (1968):  96 minutes

***Dawn of the Dead*** (1978):  127 minutes

***Day of the Dead*** (1985):  100 minutes

***Land of the Dead*** (2005):  93 minutes

***Diary of the Dead*** (2007):  92 minutes

***Survival of the Dead*** (2009):  90 minutes

#### Total:  598 minutes/9 hours, 58 minutes

---

If we add in the other movies that were made with input from George A. Romero or his co-writer on *Night of the Living Dead*, John A. Russo, the total is even more impressive:

## George A. Romero-affiliated installments:

***Night of the Living Dead*** (1990):  92 minutes<sup>1</sup>

***Dawn of the Dead*** (2004):  100 minutes<sup>1</sup>

***Day of the Dead*** (2008):  86 minutes<sup>1</sup>

#### Subtotal:  278 minutes/4 hours, 38 minutes

## John A. Russo's installments:

***Return of the Living Dead*** (1985):  91 minutes<sup>2</sup>

***Return of the Living Dead 2*** (1988):  89 minutes<sup>2</sup>

***Return of the Living Dead 3*** (1993):  97 minutes<sup>2</sup>

***Children of the Living Dead*** (2001):  90 minutes<sup>2</sup>

***Return of the Living Dead - Necropolis*** (2005):  89 minutes<sup>2</sup>

***Return of the Living Dead -  Rave to the Grave*** (2005):  94 minutes<sup>2</sup>

#### Subtotal:  550 minutes/9 hours, 10 minutes (not including the 96 minute long *Night of the Living Dead*)

#### Total:  828 minutes/13 hours, 48 minutes

### Grand total:  1,426 minutes/23 hours, 46 minutes

---

And if we add in totally unauthorized remakes which appeared because the original *Night of the Living Dead* was never properly copyrighted, and is thus considered to be in the public domain, we expand the total screentime even more:

## Unauthorized installments:

***Night of the Living Dead 3D*** (2006):  80 minutes

***Night of the Living Dead - Resurrection*** (2012):  86 minutes

***A Night of the Living Dead*** (2014):  79 minutes

***Night of the Living Dead - Genesis*** (2016):  [135 minutes](http://www.joblo.com/horror-movies/news/judith-odea-returns-in-night-of-the-living-dead-genesis-trailer-140)<sup>3</sup>

***Night of the Living Dead - Rebirth*** (2017):  90 minutes<sup>4</sup>

***Night of the Living Dead 2 - Deadlock*** (2017):  90 minutes<sup>4</sup>

***Night of the Living Dead - Contagion*** (TBD):  89 minutes

#### Total:  649 minutes/ 10 hours, 49 minutes

### Grand Total:  2,075 minutes/34 hours, 35 minutes

---

#### Caveat:

The question is limited to film, and excludes television series, but if this weren't the case, the winner would be *The Walking Dead*.

***The Walking Dead*** (through season 7, episode 6):  4,440 minutes/3 days, 2 hours, 48 minutes

***Fear the Walking Dead*** (through season 2):  903 minutes/15 hours, 3 minutes

#### Total:  5,343 minutes/3 days, 17 hours, 51 minutes

---

***Notes***:

<sup>1</sup> *These films include a credit indicating that each was "Based on a screenplay by George A. Romero", and had Romero's blessing.*

<sup>2</sup> *These films could be considered official sequels, but usually aren't.  The screenplay of the original* Night of the Living Dead *was a joint effort between George A. Romero and John A. Russo.  They disagreed over how to handle sequels for the film, and ultimately agreed to go their separate ways, with Romero's sequels having "________ of the Dead" titles, and Russo's sequels having "________ of the Living Dead" titles.  Thus, both Romero's sequels and Russo's sequels are technically true sequels to the original film, and are made by/under the aegis of the creators behind the first movie.  In the universe in which Russo's series takes place, however,* Night of the Living Dead *is a film based on real events.*

<sup>3</sup> *Includes a performance by Judith O'Dea, who played Barbra in the original* Night of the Living Dead, *lending this movie a slightly higher degree of continuity than the others in this section.*

<sup>4</sup> *Runtimes for these two films are estimates, as no official information is available.*

Answer (score 1):

The **Resident Evil** films add up to 8 hours 1 minute. Funnily enough, they're all basically the same length (between 1:34 and 1:40 long). The Romero films (I counted 7 in the " of the dead" films) add up to 10:36.

Technically speaking, however, I'm not sure that all the Romero films are "Apocalyptic" in nature, since at least some of them occurred before law & order broke down. I'm unsure, so I lumped my answer simply as "zombie" films.

Side bite: [Army of Darkness](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106308/) takes Ash back to 1300AD.  I don't know whether that qualifies as a 600 year long Apocalypse or not.  Possibly, this is a different question altogether, but seemed a fun notion.